# What's a synonym for a passionate person?

Tags: synonyms, neologisms

What's a word for a passionate person? Like a "passionista", but that of course already has another meaning. Someone that generally has strong desires, goals, or convictions, and works hard to make them a reality or prove their point. Just to be clear, I'm looking for a general term for such a person (which should be a noun, of course).

If no such word exists, then a clever neologism would be acceptable.

Comment: Passion in what context? Passionate about love, about work, about sport?

Comment: Just to be 100% clear are you *also* talking about sexual desire, or only the passion a person has for their profession/career/hobby/sport/talent etc?

Comment: @Mari-LouA more so the latter, but since I'm looking for a general term, the former can also be included (but it should not be solely the former, in meaning).

Comment: how about a go-getter?

Answer (score 5):

According to the few anthropologists brave enough to study them *in situ*, a small (not in stature) but little known tribe in the north of Ardor--the *Ardorians*--are particularly known for their passion for roasted anthropologist. Which, perhaps, explains why they are so little known. I suppose they wouldn't mind if you appropriated their name.

An alternative to Ardorian, of course, is: "**hot-blooded**" *adjective*: lustful; passionate. "*hot-blooded*, pulse-pounding passion"

*synonyms*: passionate, amorous, amatory, ***ardent***, fervid, lustful, libidinous, lecherous, sexy, virile

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=hot-blooded+definition&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=hot-blooded+definition&gs_l=hp..3.0i7i30l3j0.0.0.1.11355366...........0.FXniG7CDnyI&gws_rd=ssl)

A more moderate and general term is: **Enthusiast** *noun*: 1.  One who is filled with enthusiasm; one who is *ardently* absorbed in an interest or pursuit: a baseball *enthusiast*.

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/enthusiast)

Another term describing an individual with unusually "strong desires, goals, or convictions, and [who] works hard to make them a reality or prove their point" is as a:

> **Type A personality**
>   The theory describes "Type A" individuals as ambitious, rigidly organized, highly status-conscious, sensitive, impatient, take on more than they can handle, want other people to get to the point, anxious, proactive, and concerned with time management. People with Type A personalities are often high-achieving "workaholics" who multi-task, push themselves with deadlines, and hate both delays and ambivalence. 
>   [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_A_and_Type_B_personality_theory)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should have clearly stated that I was looking for a noun (I've updated the question to clarify that). I can't seem to put my finger on the reason, but *enthusiast* is not the sense I was going for (although it's in the ballpark). Similarly, *zealot* doesn't capture the sense of "a drive to realize strong desires, goals, or convictions" either.

Comment: +1 for enthusiast. After all, it's one of the badges on SE, so it should definitely be mentioned!

Comment: Two general observations to assist your quest, Raj: 1. Existential loneliness drives our desire to "know" or "touch" the world. This drive is often known as *Eros*, the antidote to that loneliness. 2. Our mortality, i.e., the brevity of our lives, is what makes what we do "matter". As I see it, these 2 qualities are the parents of all passion.

Comment: @Rag - Beyond the 2 existential  factors I described in the preceding comment, which are universal (though often not conscious), passion can also be ascribed to an individual's temperament. In psychology, temperament refers to those aspects of an individual's personality, such as introversion or extroversion, that are often regarded as innate rather than learned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not satisfied with [ardor](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ardor&oq=Ardor&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59.3481j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8), suggested by Little Eva, how about a *[dedicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=didicate&oq=didicate&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.41994j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=a%20dedicate)* from the verb [dedicate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dedicate)?

to devote (oneself, one's time, etc) wholly to a special purpose or cause; commit wholeheartedly or unreservedly;to devote wholly and earnestly, as to some person or purpose.

Comment: Looking for a noun.

Comment: it's all in the pronunciation, but if it's easier, what about *dedicant*?

Answer (score 0):

quaintrelle: noun - a woman who pursues a life of passion

sort of answers your question.

Comment: We'd like a source and a link for your definition.  Also note that Wikipedia has a broader definition (the female version of a dandy) than that suggested by your one line definition.  "The female counterpart is a quaintrelle, a woman who emphasizes a life of passion expressed through personal style, leisurely pastimes, charm, and cultivation of life’s pleasures."

Answer (score -1):

What about aficionado, devotee, activist, fanatic or maniac?

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but we expect long, well-researched answers that support their claims (when someone asks for a word and you;re giving near synonyms, little snippets of definition for each word help the person who asked the question select the word they like the best).