# What is the noun form of "passion" analogous to "enthusiast" for "enthusiasm"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A person who has enthusiasm for, say, language is a language enthusiast. What is a person who is passionate about language called?

> Example sentence:  He is a **[passionate guy]** in linguistics.

The closest word structurally is expert (He is an expert in linguistics), but a word that represents passion, not expertise.

Comment: I don't think there is one from _passion_. Most people use _passionate person_, or add _enthusiast_ (or synonyms) as suffix.

Comment: Well, you do see aficionado, which means both to like very much and be passionate about. Though it is not analogous in the way you would like with the same Latin root though it is from Spanish, a Latin language.

Comment: Both passionate and impassioned would work, but these are adjectives. Using an adjective as a noun, or vice versa, is common in English but I am not sure in this case it would be clear or acceptable.

Comment: Linguists study language... make a career out of it.  It seems to me that might be enough.  Would you need to say "passionate chef"  or is "chef" enough to imply that a person is passionate about cooking?  I'd say "chef" is enough.  You might need to say "amateur linguist" if they're not actually trained,  but even while tempering the title you still suggest a real passion for the field.

Comment: @PabloStraub interesting - I can see this working (maybe) with some creative license in a colloquial context. "He would see stars if asked a question in high school astronomy, but his name would definitely pop up loud and clear when asked to name a star passionate." :-)

Comment: @Tom22 - I see what you are saying, but a career and a passion for it, do not always go hand in hand.

Comment: How will you use the word? Can you write an example sentence where this word would be used?

Comment: @Rathony He is a <passionate guy> in linguistics. The closest word structurally is expert (He is an expert in linguistics), but a word that represents passion, not expertise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's a synonym for a passionate person?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227091/whats-a-synonym-for-a-passionate-person)

Comment: @Anand .. now I get what you're after.. ..

Comment: Looking at the synonyms of "passion" readily gives you: *zealot, devotee, ecstatic, activist, glorifier, venerator, worshiper, idolator, friend, yearner, lover, craver, desirer, emulator, hungerer, hankerer, thirster, longer, torch bearer*.

Answer (score 1):

[***Buff***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/buff)

> A person who is enthusiastically interested in and very knowledgeable
>   about a particular subject:
>
> *‘a computer buff’*

Answer (score 0):

Someone who loves languages is called a [*linguaphile*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/linguaphile):

> **linguaphile** - noun
>
> a lover of languages
>
> - He took a Chinese language training, he's a real linguaphile.

Macmillan Dictionary

There is no established noun form equivalent to *enthusiast*.

Comment: While it certainly answers part of the question, I don't think that is what OP asked for. _"What is the noun form of “passion” analogous to “enthusiast” for “enthusiasm”?"_

Comment: Good to know - I just picked an example to illustrate the use of "enthusiast".

Comment: Maybe *passionista*?

Comment: I considered that, but it has only made the Urban Dictionary (and indicates someone who is excessively enthusiastic about something). Also, it has an established religious usage and so may not make a very good loan word.

Answer (score 0):

***Devotee***

works with some words/fields better than others

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/devotee

> devotee
>
> noun  dev·o·tee \ˌde-ˌvō-ˈtē, ˌdē-, ˌdā-, də-, -ˈtā\
>
> an ardent follower, supporter, or enthusiast (as of a religion, art form, or sport)

He was a Jazz devotee.  She was a devotee to the Bahaus school of design .

She was a devotee to the appreciation of many languages?
She was a devotee to liguistics